# An unknown error occurred: User rejected certificate for github.com (-17) on Xcode 13.3.1

Tags: xcode, github

Since updating to XCode 13.3.1 I'm experiencing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCiw5.png) every time I try to add a dependency to a package from Github. I already added my Github account to XCode as Source Control Account but it shows up with a [warning triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hnzH.png). Weirdly enough, I'm able to add the Apple Swift Packages to my project as dependency and they are downloaded from Github.
I really hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my AdBlocker blocked the certificates from GitHub and thus making it unable to install packages.
I simply disabled my AdBlocker and everything works fine now!